# Unresolved class SearchView

Tags: android

I am trying to add menu item, but unfortunately I've got error in menu file. Below is menu item:

```
   <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="Search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@drawable/search"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

And error is in this line:

```
 app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
```

Comment: pls add your app level build.gradle file, may be need to add v7 support

Comment: I am using this instead v7 support   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0' I can't add v7 support in Android X

Comment: For androidx use `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView`

Comment: yes, whenever you use androidx support that time in Searchview use "androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"

Comment: Thank you, i changed normal searchview to this and works fine:P